# Regex that considers characters outside the match

Tags: regex, replace, sed, grep, substring

I'm wondering if it's possible to create a regex which considers characters outside of the match. So, for example, a regex which semantically means "match the characters 'hel', but only if followed by 'lo'. So in the string `hello`, it'd match `hel`.

I know that the simplest definition of regular expressions simply asks "is this string accepted as a match or not," in which case this distinction doesn't actually mean anything. But for engines that can highlight what part of a string matched (like grep/egrep) or that do replacement based on regexes (like sed), it is both meaningful and arguably very useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes, via two different mechanisms.

First, you can include the `lo` in the part of the string matched by the whole regular expression, but also have a capture group around just the `hel` part you care about.  Here's a simple demonstration with `sed` that you'll note only finds one match:

```
sed -n 's/\(hel\)lo/\1/p' <<<$'hell\nhello\nhelen'
```

Depending on your tools and goals, that may be all you need.

Secondly, you can use *lookaround* - in this case, *positive* (because you want to make sure something *is* there) *lookahead* (because you want it to be *after* the match).  The GNU implementation of `grep` has a `-P` flag to enable Perl5-compatible regular expressions, so if you're using that version, the following command has the same output as the above `sed` one:

```
grep -oP 'hel(?=lo)'  <<<$'hell\nhello\nhelen'
```

Note that OS X's system `grep` is BSD, not GNU.  I have the GNU version installed via Homebrew as `ggrep` so that I can use it when needed but am not unwittingly relying on it.

Answer (score 1):

Positive lookahead will suit this requirement:

```
hel(?=lo)
```

However unix tools like `sed` or `awk` don't have support for look arounds.

Comment: Interesting idea. It looks like that works even in tools that don't support it. For example, the impetus for my original question was to remove trailing whitespace in Sublime Text, and I tried `\s(?=$), and find-and-replace accepted it, but it also deleted the newline character. Presumably if positive lookahead was supported, this would not have happened.

Comment: I believe sublime supports it and `\s(?=$)` will definitely match end of line newline. If you want to match a whitespace but not at the end of line then use: `\s(?!$)`

Answer (score 1):

You'd want a [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
hel(?=lo)
```

Here's an demonstration: http://regexr.com/39d02

If you need to do this on the command line, as others have mentioned `sed` and `grep` don't support positive lookahead.

Here is an example using `perl`

```
echo "hello world, hel world" | perl -ne 's/hel(?=lo)/HEL/g; print;'
# HELlo world, hel world
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex lookaround. You can find very insteresting documentation here:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

> Lookahead and lookbehind, collectively called "lookaround", are
>   zero-length assertions just like the start and end of line, and start
>   and end of word anchors. The
>   difference is that lookaround actually matches characters, but then
>   gives up the match, returning only the result: match or no match. That
>   is why they are called "assertions". They do not consume characters in
>   the string, but only assert whether a match is possible or not.
>   Lookaround allows you to create regular expressions that are
>   impossible to create without them, or that would get very longwinded
>   without them.

### Positive and Negative Lookahead

> **Negative lookahead** is indispensable if you want to match something not
>   followed by something else.
>   Negative lookahead provides the solution: **q(?!u)**. The negative
>   lookahead construct is the pair of parentheses, with the opening
>   parenthesis followed by a question mark and an exclamation point.
>   Inside the lookahead, we have the trivial regex u.
>
> **Positive lookahead** works just the same. **q(?=u)** matches a q that is
>   followed by a u, without making the u part of the match. The positive
>   lookahead construct is a pair of parentheses, with the opening
>   parenthesis followed by a question mark and an equals sign.

So, as guys answered you can use a positive lookahead:

```
hel(?=lo)
```

Related to your comments, if you want to remove ending spaces, then you could use this regex:

```
\s+$
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/rX9qD4/2)**

[image]